# How to change routing in the default template of Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I just started experimenting with .NetCore MVC using Visual Studio 2017. I created a .NetCore MVC application using default template. I want to change the About route to Menu route. Therefore, I changed public IActionResult About() to public IActionResult Menu() and I changed the About.cshtml to Menu.cshtml to get the correct view. However, the template is not showing these effects. In other words, the navbar in the output is not changed. The following is my Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace RouteCheck
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and my output looks like this [The output by default template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib7Rf.png) The route [/Home/Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvyqS.png) is correctly working, but I want to change this About in the nav bar to Menu and map my route to /Home/Menu in the default template.

Comment: You can find the navbar in Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml. You will have to modify it manually.

Comment: For some reason, I thought it was automatic. Thanks!

Comment: If you want please add it as an answer and I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to modify the default navbar in Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml. That's the shared layout view in MVC default templates where the action-specific view will be rendered.